# Insert text to the beginning of every Cell in a Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to find a way to insert text in to every Cell in a specific Column.

e.g. `Column C` has `50 rows`: I need to insert `0049` to the beginning of every Cell.

I didn't had any luck finding/creating a formula for this.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a blank Column (D) and use "[CONCATENATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx)":

```
=CONCATENATE("0049",C1)
```

Drag that down for each adjacent cell in Column C and it will add 0049 as a prefix.

Comment: Thanks! I just found that and tried to replace the column with the concatenated one. Which isn't working because one part of the equation is missing.. Is there a way to instantly replace the values in a cell ? (So I have in Column C the right values)

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive? Do you need to convert forumlas to their values? When I need to do this, I copy the entire column and do a Paste Special into a new column, and choose to paste only the Values.

Comment: Yeap, "paste only Values" does the trick! Thanks.